# Is the Surface Pro 3 hardware fully supported?

Tags: hardware, macbook, surface-tablet

I'm looking at also getting either a MS Surface Pro 3 or a Macbook Air very soon, and installing elementary OS on it when I get it. My decision on which to get actually depends partly on how well the hardware of each is supported; things like the networking card, all keyboard keys, speakers, etc. Also, is the touch-screen well-supported? And how about the 'pen' / stylus?

Also directly related; is there a place where we can see information on how well supported any given device is?

Answer (score 0):

elementary doesn't support or endorse any hardware at this time. There is no official hardware compatibility database.

Specifically regarding touch, elementary OS isn't a tablet OS. Basic pointer-equivalent events should work, but things like multi-touch gestures will not.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fully answer my question. Besides the touchscreen (which I understand isn't really supported), I'd like to know if the rest of the hardware will work properly? I guess this may need a SP3 owner to answer..